# How can I pull to my shared host via Sourcetree?

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a question about working with git inside Sourcetree.
I have a local repository on my mac. The remote repository is on Bitbucket.

So when I make a change on my local computer and commit and push it, then the new changes are on Bitbucket. I can pull the changes on another local computer also with Sourcetree.

My question is now: I also have a repository on my shared webserver. Is it possible to connect the webserver also to Sourcetree and pull the newest code there too? Because now I have to connect with Terminal via ssh to my host and then write git pull. This seems to me kind of inconvenient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphical environments have a lot higher resource consumption than the command line. It's best practice to run only what you really need to run on a server - that way you can allocate the most resources to your Web page service or database or whatever - so very few servers run a GUI full-time.

Also, if your server is running Linux, then there's no Sourcetree version available. Sourcetree is only available for Windows or for macOS.

If you would like to have your server automatically update when your code updates, then you should consider using a webhook (a notification from Bitbucket of some repository event; you can configure your system to respond to the webhook by pulling the latest code) or a system like Bitbucket Pipelines which can push updated code.